# How to know how many data points Matplotlib is using for a scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new here. I was wandering if there is a simple code to print the number of data points used on a Matplotlib scatterplot and perhaps print it on the plot as "N=...".

Thank you very much

Comment: If your scatter is `plt.scatter(x,y)`, then the number of points is `N = len(x)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My scatter is plt.scatter(x,y) but x and y are series imported from excel columns with Nan values. len (x) and len (y) are different.

Comment: In that case, `len(x[~np.isnan(x) & ~np.isnan(y)])`

Comment: That worked! thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get back to the data later, and you don't have access to `x` and `y` anymore for some reason, you can retrieve them like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = ...
y = ...
artist = plt.scatter(x, y)

# ...
# Things that cause you to lose x and y.
# ...

xy = artist.get_offsets()
x, y = np.array(xy).transpose()
print(len(x))
```